# Registering Callbacks in Keras Functional API

Tags: callback, keras, tensorboard

I am learning from the Pretrained word embeddings model example at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py

I want to visualize the training process using Tensorboard. Keras has a Tensorboard callback for the `Sequential` API at https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard but not for the `Model` API that the example uses.

How do I use tensorboard for visualizing the `Model` API networks?

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks work equally well with both APIs.
I am currently using the Tensorboard callback in my model built with the Model API so I can confirm.
After defining your model with any API and compiling it simply [call](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit)

```
tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard()

model.fit(self, x, y, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```